# Google Sheets import is not changing cell value when coping data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I am using the `importrange` formula want to copy data from one Google Sheet to another. I enter the correct formula and it works but when I copy that formula to the rest of the cell expecting to copy the date in each cell it does not change the value and only copy the same data in all cell

Answer (score 0):

if your formula is like:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1A1")
```

you can unlock it for dragging down/up like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1A"&ROW(A1))
```

also do note that you can import range at once like:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1A1:A100")
```